# TypeError dropDuplicates() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I've playing streaming data in Spark 2.

I want to duplicate record with dropDuplicates method.

I've found on Spark site that I can use `dropDuplicates` with `watermark`.

This is my code with watermark without `dropDuplicates` method:

```
parsed = parsed_opc \
    .withWatermark("sourceTimeStamp", "10 minutes") \
    .groupBy(
        window(parsed_opc.sourceTimeStamp, "4 seconds"),
        parsed_opc.id
    ) \
    .agg({"value": "avg"}) \
    .withColumnRenamed("avg(value)", "avg")\
    .orderBy("avg", ascending=True)
```

This code works. But whn I want to add `dropDuplicates` like this:

```
parsed = parsed_opc \
    .withWatermark("sourceTimeStamp", "10 minutes") \
    .dropDuplicates("id", "sourceTimeStamp") \
    .groupBy(
        window(parsed_opc.sourceTimeStamp, "4 seconds"),
        parsed_opc.id
    ) \
    .agg({"value": "avg"}) \
    .withColumnRenamed("avg(value)", "avg")\
    .orderBy("avg", ascending=True)
```

It throws an error : `TypeError: dropDuplicates() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

I don't understand why this error throwns. This usage is also in Spark site with like this. 
What is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use brackets to declare more than one column in your `dropDuplicates()` method.

Like this:

```scala
parsed = parsed_opc \
    .withWatermark("sourceTimeStamp", "10 minutes") \
    .dropDuplicates(["id", "sourceTimeStamp"]) \
    .groupBy(
        window(parsed_opc.sourceTimeStamp, "4 seconds"),
        parsed_opc.id
    ) \
    .agg({"value": "avg"}) \
    .withColumnRenamed("avg(value)", "avg")\
    .orderBy("avg", ascending=True)
```